# Deleting mySQL records with ajax, php, and javascript

Tags: mysql, ajax

I have made a simple comment system [here](http://class.piezosystems.org/finder-admin/finder/comment/), and I would like to create a delete button where if pressed the comment will be deleted (essentially removed from database). I don't know how to implement this on the comment. I have made javascript to interact with delta.php, but I do not know how to make the delete.php. The mySQL fields are;

- Id,
- Name,
- Url,
- Email and
- Body

How do i code the delete.php to interact with the mySQL and the comment system? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteUser(id){
    new Ajax.Request('delete.php', {
        parameters: $('idUser'+id).serialize(true),
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: POST the comment ID into delete.php and then in turn pass that to your query which then simply deletes the row with that id. What do you have so far in terms of delete.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to make things easier:

```
$('#delete_button').click(function(){
   var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');//you should use the id of the comment as id for the delete button for this to work.
   $.post('delete.php', {'comment_id' : comment_id}, function(){
      $(this).parent('div').remove(); //hide the comment from the user
   });
});
```

delete.php would contain something like:

```
<?php
//include database configuration file here. 
//If you don't know how to do this just look it up on Google.

$comment_id = $_POST['comment_id'];

mysql_query("DELETE comment from TABLE WHERE comment_id='$comment_id'");
//mysql_query is not actually recommended because its already being deprecated. 
//I'm just using it for example sake. Use pdo or mysqli.  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

**Javascript**:

```js
function deleteComment(id)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php?id="+id,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(result)
        {
            if(result == "Ok") alert("The comment is successfuly deleted");
            else alert("The following error is occurred: "+result);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP (delete.php):**

```php
if(!isset($_POST['id'])) die("No ID specified");
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `comments` WHERE `id` = $id") or die(mysql_error());

echo "Ok";
```